# Interpretation of PCA principal components

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, pca

As a result of a PCA analysis with some initial correlated variables $X_1,..,X_k$ we often do a plot of the loadings to intepret the principal components:

**PLOT 1: Plot of the loadings:**

We call $v^i,i=1..K$ the principal components (so that $v^{i}\cdot v^{j}=\delta_{i,j}$). Indicating the components with a lower index $v^i_a,i=1..K,a=1...K$, we plot for a fixed i the loadings $v^i_a, a=1...K$.

Given the formula for every data point $x$:

$x=\sum_i (v^{i}\cdot x) \  v^i$,

we can interpret $v^i_a$ as the contribution of variable $a$ to component $i$.

Alternatively we can do what I call here a correlation plot (my terminology):

**PLOT 2: Correlation plot:**

We can interprest a principal component $i$ defining the score $S^{i}=\sum_a X_a v_a^{i}$ (by theory $E[S^{i}S^{j}]=0$ if $i \ne j$), and define $y^{i}_a \equiv E[S^{i}X_a]=\sum_{a'}E[X_aX_{a'}]v_{a'}^{i} $. We can plot (at fixed $i$) $y^{i}_a$ as a function of $a$ and interpret $y^i_a$ as the contribution of variable $a$ to the principal component $i$ as well.

**Question:** which one is the more meaningful plot to intepret the principal components? I would be tempted to say that the correlation plot does not make much sense because the $X_a$ are not independent. Therefore a correlation between $S_i$ and $X_a$ could be spurious and due to a correlation between $S_i$ and an $X_b$ with whom $X_a$ is correlated . But I would like to know other opinions (since I am not sure) and if the correlation plot has some application or interpretation.

**PS:** Note that the correlation plot, according to my understanding, is very much related to the circle plot, where one tries to intepret/group the original variables (not the principal components) by considering, at a fixed original variable $a$, $y^{i}_a$ as a function of $i$ (in a circle plot just for i=1,2). Told another way, in this context a parallel of the correlation plot similar to the circle plot, would be a plot where (at fixed original variable $a$) $y^{i}_a$ is plotted as a function of $i$. Since the $S_i$ are independent between each other maybe the spurious effect discussed above does not show up.

Any opinion/comments/answers? I am always confused about PCA intepretation and would like to fill this hole in my understanding...

Comment: I think it would help if you showed examples.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, even if showing examples takes always time :)... but I will add one as soon as I have time (in a few days probably)